# Неправильно показывает разницу в минутах

Tags: php

Подскажите почему неправильно показывает разницу в минутах

```
<?php


    $recordTime     = date_create('2018-03-12 02:02:31');
    $timeNow        = date_create('2018-03-12 03:10:27');
    $timediff       = date_diff($recordTime, $timeNow)->i;

    print_r($timediff);
?>
```

Comment: показывает 7 минут разницу

Comment: Все правильно показывает. В свойства объекта смотрите `[y] => 0
    [m] => 0
    [d] => 0
    [h] => 1
    [i] => 7
    [s] => 56`

Answer (score 3):

Переведите свои даты в метки времени Unix и посчитайте их разницу:

```
var_dump((strtotime('2018-03-12 03:10:27') - strtotime('2018-03-12 02:02:31')) / 60);
```

Результат

```
float(67.933333333333)
```

Answer (score 0):

Если распечатаете просто `date_diff($recordTime, $timeNow)`, а не только `i`, то увидите, что все показывается правильно. Вы просто запрашиваете только минуты :)

```
DateInterval Object
(
    [y] => 0
    [m] => 0
    [d] => 0
    [h] => 1
    [i] => 7
    [s] => 56
    [weekday] => 0
    [weekday_behavior] => 0
    [first_last_day_of] => 0
    [invert] => 0
    [days] => 0
    [special_type] => 0
    [special_amount] => 0
    [have_weekday_relative] => 0
    [have_special_relative] => 0
)
```

Comment: То есть это получается без учета часа?

Comment: Да. Разница представляет из себя структуру (или объект, как больше нравится) в которой показана разница именно по отдельным полям времени, тоесть: разница только в секундах, в минутах, часах, днях, годах и т.д.
Тоесть, если вы хотите получить разницу ВООБЩЕ в минутах, то вам надо пройтись по каждому полю и умножать его на количество минут в каждой еденице (в часе их 60, в дне их 24*60 и т.д.)

Comment: Наверное правильнее написать разница не в минутах, а разница минут, разница часов, разница дней - тогда это более точно (для меня по крайней мере :))

Comment: Вы сравниваете два объекта, а не числа. Вот и получаете diff объект в котором разница записана по годам, дням, часам, минутам, секундам и миллисекундам.